# I get a 403 forbidden error when trying to remove the .php extension using .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp, httpd.conf

I want to remove the .php extension from the URL using a .htaccess file located in the same folder as the php files (I want to remove the extension for all of the files, not just one of them). I use the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks # I found this on the Internet trying to solve this problem, but nothing changed
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app_tests/ # This is the folder where I want to delete the .php extension, it's located in the htdocs folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L] #I have tried without QSA as well (I don't really know what it does)
```

So theoretically, when I go to myweb.com/index I should see the index.php page but I get a 403 error (forbidden) when entering that address. Of course, there is no directory called index. I know that the code works (or at least does something) because when I write it wrong it says internal server error and because if I erase or comment it (#) the error I get is 404 (not found).

I'm using one of the lastest versions of XAMPP for Windows. I've uncommented the following line in the httpd.conf file to have the module loaded:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Do anyone know what I've done wrong or how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably failing, because you have comments after the directives. In .htaccess comments must be on their own line, they cannot come after a rule/condition.

I will help you with the task at hand by sharing a snippet from my stack. Put this .htaccess file inside the folder where you want the .php-less file access to work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app_tests/

# Set an S for HTTPS protocol
# helps for rewrites with protocol specific URL
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}s ^(443(s)|[0-9]+s)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [ENV=SFORSSL:%2]

# remove trailing slashes if it's not a directory
# you will need this, because if a trailing slash is added wrongly
# the condition for the next group of rules will fail
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http%{ENV:SFORSSL}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

# internally rewrite to .php if a file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

QSA, stands for Query String Append, it basically appends to the URL all the request parameters that the GET request includes (everything after the ? in the URL).

Comment: I didn't know about the comment rules in .htaccess, thanks. Anyway, I wrote those comments when I pasted the code here. Your code is not working for me (i get a 404 not found error)... maybe it's a httpd.conf misconfiguration? I've uncommented the line [LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so], is that enough? Thank you!!

Comment: @JorgeBruned Check now, I updated my code a bit to take into account your rewrite base.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's working fine! One last question, now my URLs look like http://mywebsite.com/app_tests/index(.php) // http://mywebsite.com/app_tests/app/alumnos(.php), but how can I remove the "app_tests" folder from the URL if the domain is "mywebsite.com" (not if it's for example "yourwebsite.com")? I can't manage to do it. Thanks again!

Comment: @JorgeBruned I suppose you are working in a test environment. You shouldn't worry about that for now. When you put your code live on the root of a domain. It will just work from your root website, for example mywebsite.com/index.

Comment: Actually I'm not working in a test environment, the word 'tests' is part of the name of the web app I've done. The problem is that I want to have more than one website in a single web server, so I want to remove the name of the folder from the URL just if the domain is "mywebsite.com". If it's too complex or even impossible, I would like to know how to remove a folder from the URL (without any conditions). Thank you :)

Comment: @JorgeBruned when you make the domain configuration, if you set the document_root for that particular domain to be this app_tests folder, then you will not need to do anything to remove it from URL. If you set yourotherdomain.com to have another document_root, that other domain will not have the name of the folder on the URL.

Comment: @Shaf Ok, it finally worked. Thank you for your help, I know pretty much about PHP, MySQL, etc. but it's my first time using my own server (until I got optic fibre last month, my connection was really bad). Thanks again!

Comment: @JorgeBruned Glad you had it figured out. Cheers!